# is there any way to use localStorage.getItem in Next js with redux toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, local-storage, redux-toolkit

I used localStorage.setItem() inside the redux toolkit slice it does work but when I want to use localStorage.getItem() in the side redux toolkit slice it does not work and it says local storage is not defined

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";


const users=localStorage.getItem('users')!==null ?JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")):[];
const initialState = { value: users };
const Users = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: (state, action) => {
      state.value.push(action.payload);
      localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(state.value.map(item=>item)))
    },},});

export const { addUser} = Users.actions;
export default Users.reducer;
```

But it says
[image]

Comment: `localStorage` is in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to use redux-persist it's a redux abstraction for `localstorage`. If for any reason you can't use it try to check if the window is defined before using `localsotarge`.

```js
if(window !== 'undefined'){
// do tome smth...
}
```